# Showing username in url without controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

Hope everyone's good this morning. Been learning rails lately, and been working on a little "social" app for practice. I've looked around for a good answer for this, but couldn't find the right thing for me. Here's what I'm trying to figure out now:

By default, the url is hi.com/user/12, and so far I've changed that to /user/name. Everything works fine there. But of course, I want to take it further and do hi.com/name (mostly because I want to learn how it's done properly).

Here's my (abbreviated) routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end

root to: 'pages#home'

match '/help',    to: 'pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'

match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

Here's the show view from the controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  @tweets = @user.tweets.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Now what I've tried is to stick `match ':username', to: 'users#show'` in my routes, and then change `find_by_username(params[:id])` in the controller to `find_by_username(params[:username])`. This actually works really well, and shows all proper user info on hi.com/name. The following and followers are still (as expected) on user/name/following (and they work fine). However, all static pages break, including /signout (kinda important :p), and while /users still shows an index of all users, users/name throws an error (if /name works, then I wouldn't need /users/name anyway). The error being *undefined method `tweets' for nil:NilClass* in the users controller.

Again what I'm trying to accomplish is hi.com/username and hi.com/username/following, etc. Also need my static pages to still work. I have everything working with /users/name, but I want to learn how to make it work this way too.

Thanks everyone, I appreciate it!

Comment: Just as a recommendation: When creating a question, stick to the essential information. You can dispense with the opening paragraph and the closing one. We prefer the facts and information necessary to give you a good answer. Narrative beyond that isn't really needed and risks "TL;DR" responses.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. I just like to give a little context, plus I'm a noob so I'm not quite sure what info might/might not be needed. Thanks!

Comment: If additional information is needed people will ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's easy but it has side effects.

Just add at the end of your `routes.rb`:

```
get '/:id', to: 'user#show'
```

But, a user named `about`, or `users` or `pages` won't be able to see their profile, because the path is used earlier in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: For a quick and easy fix, this is great. From my understanding, this looks for a profile on the url and if there is one, it shows it. Definitely works, REST routes still have to go through /users/name/. My follow-up question(s) would be: what's the best way to prevent people from signing-up with static page names? And what should I do with the /users/name/ routes that still work, but are just duplicates? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Have a blacklist of usernames they can't select. 2) have those match the router before your route above.